# How to make blink effect on textview on click?

Tags: android, onclick, textview

Hi I am new to android development. I want to create onclick effects to textview. When I click on the textview it will blink or something effects make. I tried it with change color, but it's not working. How can I make blink effect on textview onclick ??
please help me with example code. thanks in advance :)

Comment: bling means click effect or an animation after clicking on textview

Answer (score 47):

The easiest way is to set this background in the *TextView*:

```
 android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

And if you want to set a different color for the background, set that *attr* as `foreground` instead of `background`.

Comment: what if i have a drawable in background attr. I tried :  android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" and my custom drawable as foreground. But the text i wrote on textview using android:text="@string/login_label" doesn't show in that case.

Comment: Because the foreground covers the text. Do it the other way around, put your custom drawable as the background and the `attr` as the foreground

Answer (score 17):

try this. it worked for me.

```
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 7):

create a xml with name something like txt_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

then add in texview xml

```
android:background="@drawable/txt_bg"
android:clickable="true"
```

hope it will help.

Answer (score 4):

try below code:-

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/action"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_click"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
```

**btn_click.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_hover" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button"/> 

</selector>
```

or below also

**btn_hover.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="#1a000000"
        android:endColor="#33000000"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent" >
    </gradient>

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

**btn.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke 
        android:color="#000000"
        android:width="1dp"
        />
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent" >
    </gradient>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

**btn_click.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_hover" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: but you used button_hover, which is an image right ??

Comment: try it and then let me know.

Comment: what ur linearlayout background color (if layout color white then change to black)

Comment: @Maxwell then change color of btn_hover and btn drawable

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TesteBlinkActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        blink();
}

private void blink(){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        int timeToBlink = 1000;    //in milissegunds
        try{Thread.sleep(timeToBlink);}catch (Exception e) {}
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                    public void run() {
                    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usage);
                    if(txt.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                        txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }else{
                        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    blink();
                }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
```